# git pull merges automatically

Tags: git, merge, pull

I've a `master` branch and a `feature_swap` branch. I want to continue working on these two branches in parallel. I did some change on `master` and then committed. I wanted to apply some algorithm changes of `master` to `feature_swap` branch and see how that version works. So I did

```
git pull origin feature_swap
```

and got this message

```
 * branch            feature_swap -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging collator.h
Merge made by recursive.
```

I don't want to merge. Rather I just want to put some selected changes that I applied on `master` to `feature_swap` (maybe by copy pasting). And if that fits my expectation, I'll make another commit to that branch with those changes. Which I again want paralally.

I'm afraid, I'vent done a `git push` yet. I can see `merge branch 'feature_swap'` in `git log`. What I need to do now to restore the state ?

Answer (score 11):

Considering the definition of `git pull` is `git fetch && git merge`, the merge isn't unexpected.

You might want to to do `git rebase master` instead, which will reapply the commits in `master` onto `feature_swap`. Combined with `cherry-pick` you can specify the commits you want.

To `fetch` from the remote, simply use `git fetch` which will download the commits from the remote but doesn't apply them.

Comment: would That push these changes to upstream ? e.g. would I see traces of these dirty works in my bitbucket repo ?

Comment: Until you do a `git push`, nothing will be visible outside of your repository, ever. You are free to use `rebase` to modify the structure of your commits, and only when you push, it will be visible.

Comment: also `rebase master` says `Current branch master is up to date.`

Comment: You need to be in the branch you want to rebase to.

Comment: so I did `git rebase feature_swap` and now I don't see that 'auto merge' in `git log`

Comment: You can follow these steps : First "git fetch" the remote. Then "git merge v1.0 --no-commit --no-ff " it to feature-swap branch. Now do the testings you want on the feature-swap branch. If you're satisfied, continue with the commit. If not, do a "git --hard reset" (be careful to save any files on the branch, it will return to the state prior to the pull)